Dynamically define variable name outside context manager
I have setup like this
# main.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        globals()[self.name] = self
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exec_type, exec_value, traceback) -> bool:
        return False

with A('foo'): pass
print(foo)

even though Pylance screams at me, It works and i am able to see that foo exists. but if I split the code like
# ./src/module_name/fileA.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name: str = name

    def __enter__(self):
        globals()[self.name] = self
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exec_type, exec_value, traceback) -> bool | None:
        return None

and
# ./tests/test_fileA.py
from module_name.fileA import A

with A('foo'): pass
print(foo)

it gives the error NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
what can i do ?
i don't want a syntax like with A('foo') as foo: pass
I am using Python3.11 on Ubuntu 20.04, trying to make my first python package.
If possible please suggest a pythonic way to do this
EDIT: -
considering the suggestions, I wanted to add some context
i wanted to make a dynamic namespace generator like
with A('foo'):
  class B: pass
  def c():pass
  foo.add(B)
  foo.add(c)

foo.B()
foo.c()


That seems like a weird use case for a context manager. Context managers are for managing resources within a context, explicitly not leaking them outside the context.

You should structure your code to be used like this: foo = A('foo') and then with foo: pass (however if you actually only created the context manager to add foo to the global scope, the with statement is now pointless and you should remove it).

I don’t understand, why not use with A() as foo?

@dROOOze That actually makes more sense then what i was trying to do. Thanks a lot! I should probably stop coding at 3 in the morning....

Every module has its own global namespace. In your second example, A.__enter__ is injecting foo into module_name.fileA's namespace, not __main__'s namespace.
# ./tests/test_fileA.py
from module_name.fileA import A

with A('foo'): pass
print(module_name.fileA.foo)

